# Trying to get property 'department' of non-object in laravel with one to many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Actually I want to relationship with two tables one is the student table where some data of a student. another table has department notice. I want to access the department notice according to the student department. The student has login id, password, dept & much other information of an individual student on the student table. The screenshot is given below

[image]

Now I want to try to access according to the dept.  Another Table dept. the screenshot is given below.

[image]
Here given the CseDepartment model

```
 public function administration()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Administration','dept');
}
```

Administration model

```
 public function department()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\CseDepartment','dept');
}
```

function is given below

```
public function individualdepartment(){
        $this->AdminAuthCheck();
        $id=Session::get('id');
        $student=Administration::find($id);

        return view('Student.department',compact('student'));
    }
```

view page department

```
@foreach ($student as $students)
                    {{-- expr --}}

                <tr>
                    <td>{{$students->department->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$students->department->message}}</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

Comment: I can see you are using `$students->department` in the loop that should be `$student->department`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **controller**, you are calling the `find()` method, which gives you *one* object, a `student`.

```
$student=Administration::find($id);
```

In your **blade** page, you are then asking to loop on that single object and produce a collection:

```
@foreach ($student as $students) // There is only ONE student, this will not loop.
```

If you want the above to work, you can grab a collection from your **controller**:

```
// Note the plural naming convention to make it a little more clear
$students=Administration::all(); 
return view('Student.department',compact('students'));
```

Then in your **blade** file, you can loop like this:

```
@foreach ($students as $student)  // note the name plural --> singluar
            <tr>
                <td>{{$student->department->name}}</td>  // Now you have a single student
                <td>{{$student->department->message}}</td>
```

This will resolve the non-object error.